# How to add "Family Member Information" Columns to Event Attendee List report?

Tags: civievent, civireport, column

[image]

Is it possible to add Family Member Information columns to this screen? I run a youth program and it would be helpful to be able to pull emergency contact information when running the report. Very new to Civi.

Answer (score 2):

All the checkboxes in the screenshot you posted refer to built-in CiviCRM fields. "Family Member Information" doesn't refer to any built-in CiviCRM field, so it's a bit hard to know exactly what you're asking to do.  Here are some options:

- If "Family Member Information" is the name of a *custom field group*, then you can add those checkboxes to the report by going to **Administer menu » Customize Data and Screens » Custom Fields**.  Find the *Family Member Information* custom group and click **View and Edit Custom Fields**.  Change any field you'd like to appear on this report such that **Searchable** is set to **Yes**.
- If "Family Member Information" is set via a relationship, you have a few options.  I won't detail them here unless you update the question to indicate this is the case, but:

  - Add folks to a group, use the Relationship Report.
  - The Extended Reports extension has an Event Attendee List report with relationships.
  - If you're using Drupal, this is easy to implement using Views.